# issue with FileUpload Control in ASP.NET & Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Friends I need your help to fix an issue.

**DETAIL**
I have a Registration form based on update panel (works in slides) where one slide asks the user to upload his/her photo (optional).

**ISSUE**
Everything works fine, fine name is saved in Database, user folder creates in server side But the file is not uploaded ... no error.

**CODES**

> @primePhoto -- FileUpload1

```
 protected void RegisterClick6(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pathToCreate = "img/users/" + userName.Text;
    if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate)))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
    }

    String imageFolder = pathToCreate;
    String savePath;
    String saveFile;
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        savePath = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, imageFolder);
        saveFile = Path.Combine(savePath, FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(saveFile);
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str1);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "RegisterUser";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postDate", currentDate.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@primePhoto", FileUpload1.FileName);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    multiview1.SetActiveView(view7);        
}
```

Comment: Have you used the form tag? enctype="multipart/form-data" as in: <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: no and i dont know about it

Comment: ok, I did that but still no result :(

Comment: The content of the html form please and a response.write for the value of saveFile. Do you have write rights on the directory savePath on OS level? [grant to test modify right to authenticated users for that folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add trigger to update panel as like:

```
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="RegisterClick6" />
        </Triggers>
```